# Getting duplicate button when mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to loop through an array of Invitation from a team and a user can have many Invitation. So right now I want to when I clicked invite button, Invitation will be added into user object.

Here is how my project look like:
[image]

Here is when I am in another team:
[image]

So I want to implement a way that when user have Invitation the invite button will be disappear, and if we search from another team that have teamId different with the Invitations.teamId and the button will appear. How can I do that?

I add example in my codesandbox for easy to work on: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-hugle-4m835?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a function that verifies that the user already had an invitation.

```
import "./styles.css";
import InviteCard from "./InviteCard";

export default function App() {
  const thisTeamId = 3;

  const users = [
    {
      InvitesApplications: [{ teamId: 1 }, { response: "Waiting on response" }],
      Memberships: [{ teamId: 2 }, { response: "Waiting on response" }],
      fullname: "Nathan"
    },
    {
      InvitesApplications: [{ teamId: 2 }, { response: "Waiting on response" }],
      Memberships: [{ teamId: 1 }],
      fullname: "Nick"
    },
    {
      InvitesApplications: [
        { teamId: 2, response: "Waiting on response" },
        { teamId: 1, response: "Waiting on response" },
        { teamId: 3, response: "Waiting on response" }
      ],
      Memberships: [],
      fullname: "Nancy"
    }
  ];

  const isInvitationAvailable = (teamId, invitations) => {
        const index= invitations.findIndex(invitation => invitation.teamId === teamId)
        return index > -1
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {users
        .filter(
          (user) =>
            user.Memberships.length < 1 ||
            user.Memberships.every((member) => member.teamId !== thisTeamId)
        )
        .map((user, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <InviteCard user={user} thisTeamId={thisTeamId} />
            {!isInvitationAvailable(thisTeamId, user.InvitesApplications)  && <button>Invite</button>}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you only want to use a `map` if you want to produce *multiple* buttons.  If you just want to produce a single button ... but only when you have 1+ users, you could simply write:

```
{users.length && <button>Invite</button>}
```

Comment: I mean I want the button to show when a user from another team search and will show the invite button if that user wasn't get any invite from that team yet. And when a user from another team invite them when they already got an invitation from that team the button will dissapear